# Searching on solr with word having dot(.)

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

The words which ends with a . are giving me problem on solr.
when i search for query `l.l.*`
i get result as  `l.l.p , l.l.a etc...`
but i do not get result `l.l.`

i have set the analyzer as follows

```
   <field name="C" type="text_general" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true">
   <analyzer>
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
   </field>
```

I want every word starting with words like l.l. and a exact match should also appear.

Comment: What query parser are you using in your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear in your question what query parser are you using, I assume edismax.

So, the star character `*` used in query parser matches one or more characters.

If you want match also `1.1.` you should add `OR` clause:

```
("1.1." OR 1.1.*)
```

in SolrJ you would translate it in:

```
solrQuery.setQuery("(\"1.1.\" OR 1.1.*)");
```

Another way you have is add a regular expression directly your Solr query.

In your case is something like this:

```
field:/1\.1\..*/
```

in SolrJ you would translate it in:

```
solrQuery.setQuery("field:/1\\.1\\..*/");
```

> Solr 4.0 added regular expression support, which means that '/' is now a special character and must be escaped if searching for literal forward slash.

Have a look at [SolrQuerySyntax](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax) and [Solr Regex Query Tutorial](http://www.openjems.com/solr-regex-tutorial/)

Comment: I am using solrj for the query freedev

Comment: I have just added the SolrJ version

Comment: thanks freedev.  the last . was creating a problem now if i pass my query like l.l\.* it works fine. May be it interpreted .* somehow differently.

Comment: Not sure I got what's your last query. Is that `setQuery("1.1\\.*");` ?